# Is there a way to make sure the round function always rounds up?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Question is 2 parts. 
1st - I have a simple rounding function for a column in my query but I need it to round up in all cases. 
2nd - this calculation yields multiple records for each calculation

NumOfBoxes: Round([Orders].[Qty]/[PartsFinished].[BoxQuantity],0)

With regard to the multiple records it does this - 
Example: order qty is 1000, box qty is 250, NumOfBoxes is 4 but this returns 4 separate lines instead of just one. If the answer to the calculation is 15 it returns 15 lines. I have no idea why.

Comment: I resolved the multiple record issue, I just totaled and grouped my results. I still don't know how to make it round up in every calculation though.

Comment: I actually resolved both of my own issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Int(([Orders].[Qty] + [PartsFinished].[BoxQuantity] - 1)/[PartsFinished].[BoxQuantity])
```

`Int` truncates, but you're in effect adding a number less than one, so this will always round up, unless the number is exactly an integer, in which case it won't round up. This is probably the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: @Rats: Only here where you have integers. Not always if Qty could be a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Use the *core method* for rounding up:

```
NumOfBoxes: -Int(-[Orders].[Qty]/[PartsFinished].[BoxQuantity])
```

You may also wish study my article at *Experts Exchange* and code collection on *GitHub*:

[Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/20299/Rounding-values-up-down-by-4-5-or-to-significant-figures.html)

[VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

If you have no EE account, browse for the link: *Read the full article*

Comment: That's really clever! +1 Guaranteed to be "fixed" by some naive developer. I'd put a comment each time it's used: `'This rounds up. Yes, it has two minus signs. Yes, it works. Do not touch!'`

Answer (score 0):

To systematically round up a number, simply use round(number+0,5). You can also use ceil(number).